# Complete measure

Tags: measure-theory

When we have a general probability space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ there is a process of making it a complete measure space, called the completion.

Well, my question is quite related to this: given a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ could we construct a probability $\mu$ with respect to wich the space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is complete?  Is there such a construction in any particular example, like $X$ metric compact with borel $\sigma$-álgebra or others?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial, and on top of that negative answer, but anyway: There is no complete finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the interval $[0,1]$. Indeed, let $\mu$ be a finite measure on that $\sigma$-algebra. We can suppose that it is non-atomic (i.e. we remove the countably many possible points such that $\mu(\{x\})>0$), and that $\mu(K)>0$ for every sub-interval of $[0,1]$ (otherwise $\mu$ is certainly incomplete). So it means that there is a strictly increasing continuous bijective function $F:[0,1]\to J$, where $J\subset\mathbb R$ is an interval, such that $\mu(A)=\lambda(F(A))$ ($\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $J$). So our measure space is isomorphic to $J$ with $\lambda$ (and with Borel $\sigma$-algebra) - but that is not complete.

If I remember correctly, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of almost any reasonable (=Polish) space is isomorphic to that of $[0,1]$, so this counterexample is reasonably general.